# Range values in C

Tags: c, arrays

So I want to solve a problem in **C**
We have 10 numbers {1,1,8,1,1,3,4,9,5,2} in an array. We break the array into 3 pecies A, B, C.

And wemake the bellow procedure (I prefered to create a small diagram so you can undertand me better). [Diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qVss.png)

As you see this isn't all the procedure just the start of it.

I created a code but I getting false results. What have I missed?

```
#define N 10

int sum_array(int* array, int first, int last) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = first ; i <= last ; i++) {
        res += array[i];
    }
    return res;
}
int main(){

    int array[N] = {1,1,8,1,1,3,4,9,5,2};
    int Min = 0;
    for (int A = 1; A < N - 2; A++) {
        int ProfitA = sum_array(array, 0 ,  A-1);
        int ProfitB = array[A];
        int ProfitC = sum_array(array,A+1,N-1);
        for (int B = 1; B < N - 1; B++) {
                //here the values are "current" - valid
                int temp = (ProfitA < ProfitB)    ? ProfitA : ProfitB;
                Min =  (ProfitC < temp) ? ProfitC : temp;
                //Min = std::min(std::min(ProfitA,ProfitB),ProfitC);
                if (Min > INT_MAX){
                    Min = INT_MAX;

                }

                //and here they are being prepared for the next iteration
                ProfitB = ProfitB + array[A+B-1];
                ProfitC = ProfitC - array[A+B];
        }
}
    printf("%d", Min);
    return 0;
}
```

*Complexity of program is Ο(n* (n+n))=O(n^2 )

To find the number of permutations here is the function : 1+0.5*N*(N-3) where N is the number of elements in the array.*

Here is the first though of the program in pseudocode. Complexity O(n^3)

```
   //initialization, fills salary array 
n:= length of salary array 
best_min_maximum:=infinity 
current_min_maximum:=infinity 
best_bound_pos1 :=0 
best_bound_pos2 :=0 
for i = 0 .. (n-2): 
>> for j = (i+1) .. (n-1) 
>>>> current_min_maximum = max_bros_profit(salary, i, j) 
>>>> if current_min_maximum < best_min_maximum: 
>>>>>> best_min_maximum:=current_min_maximum 
>>>>>> best_bound_pos1 :=i 
>>>>>> best_bound_pos2 :=j 

max_bros_profit(profit_array, position_of_bound_1, position_of_bound_2) 
so max_bros_profit([8 5 7 9 6 2 1 5], 1(==1st space between days, counted from 0) , 3) is interpreted as: 
8 . 5 | 7 . 9 | 6 .2 . 1 . 5 - which returns max sum of [8 5] [7 9] [6 2 1 5] => 14 
> ^ - ^ - ^ - ^ - ^ - ^ - ^ 
> 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6
```

Comment: Pardon me, but if its `c++`, why `printf()`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Ο.ο yes I just forgot to point out I use c libraries. No big deal!

Comment: `sum_array` could probably be rewritten using dynamic programming.

Comment: @stuXnet If you sum every line A,B,C one of these are the highest number. If you sum all the procedure you have a new row Lowest. From that we want the lowest value!

Comment: Your diagram is not making it any clearer, are you trying to find the breakdown that gives you the lowest (minimum) sum for each group?

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis yes more less that. Do you want me to post the problem?

Comment: @Opo: Shouldn't there be a linear-time greedy algorithm starting with the configuration ({a[0]},{a[1],...,a[n-2]},{a[n-1]}). By iteratively filling the smallest bucket from {A,C} (without increasing the current minimum) you should arrive at the optimal solution. There should not be any non-global local minima. The optimal solution for your example appears to be 15.

Comment: It would be helpful to what you are trying to achieve.  If you want to try every possible division of the array into A,B & C, and find the minimum of each, then you are looking at O(N^3) I would think.  O(N^2) to break down, 3*O(N) to sum.  I wonder if it would be possible to squeeze the middle until you can find the optimal minimum for each set and make it an O(N) solution.

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis the problem seems easy to undestand but difficult to achive for me. Please explain to me more. First I want to know if everyone understand the problem correctly!

Comment: @Opo if you're going to require answers to be written as C please do not tag with C++. The answers for C++ are *very* different than the answers for C.

Comment: yes I din't know that I shouldn't use C++ tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my take. It is a greedy algorithm that starts with a maximal B range and then starts chopping off values one after another until the result cannot be improved. It hast complexity `O(n)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

// Splits an array `arr` into three sections A,B,C.
// Returns the indices to the first element of B and C.
//    (the first element of A obviously has index 0)
template <typename T, ::std::size_t len>
::std::pair<::std::size_t,::std::size_t> split(T const (& arr)[len]) {
  assert(len > 2);
  // initialise the starting indices of section A, B, and C
  //   such that A: {0}, B: {1,...,len-2}, C: {len-1}
  ::std::array<::std::size_t,3> idx = {0,1,len-1};
  // initialise the preliminary sum of all sections
  ::std::array<T,3> sum = {arr[0],arr[1],arr[len-1]};
  for (::std::size_t i = 2; i < len-1; ++i)
    sum[1] += arr[i];
  // the preliminary maximum
  T max = ::std::max({ sum[0], sum[1], sum[2] });
  // now we iterate until section B is not empty
  while ((idx[1]+1) < idx[2]) {
    // in our effort to shrink B, we must decide whether to cut of the
    //   left-most element to A or the right-most element to C.
    //   So we figure out what the new sum of A and C would be if we
    //   did so.
    T const left = (sum[0] + arr[idx[1]]);
    T const right = (sum[2] + arr[idx[2]-1]);
    // We always fill the smaller section first, so if A would be
    //    smaller than C, we slice an element off to A.
    if (left <= right && left <= max) {
      // We only have to update the sums to the newly computed value.
      // Also we have to move the starting index of B one
      //    element to the right
      sum[0] = left;
      sum[1] -= arr[idx[1]++];
      // update the maximum section sum
      max = ::std::max(sum[1],sum[2]); // left cannot be greater
    } else if (right < left && right <= max) {
      // Similar to the other case, but here we move the starting
      //    index of C one to the left, effectively shrinking B.
      sum[2] = right;
      sum[1] -= arr[--idx[2]];
      // update the maximum section sum
      max = ::std::max(sum[1],sum[0]); // right cannot be greater
    } else break;
  }
  // Finally, once we're done, we return the first index to
  //    B and to C, so the caller knows how our partitioning looks like.
  return ::std::make_pair(idx[1],idx[2]);
}
```

It returns the index to the start of the B range and the index to the start of the C range.

Comment: hahah yes, you forgot the main()! hahaha Don't you worry. But if you want place it in your code

Comment: hahaha? I didn't forget anything. This function provides the functionality you described. If you are uncertain how to call a function, might I suggest to brush up on your C++ a bit?

Comment: As I say I don't want to use c++11 which I saw you didn't. Anyway I think it's good answer but I am not an C++ expert. Only C. I will accept your answet though. If you want to make it in C I would apreciate. And what was the problem in my code?

Comment: @bitmask Can you explain this to me? For each "A" partition of `arr` you seem to have only one partitioning of the rest of `arr`.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Yes? Did I misunderstand the problem? You're looking for a minimising partition of `arr` into A,B,C. such that the maximum of all individual sums of A,B and C is minimised. I claim (and have kind of a pseudo-proof in my head) that such a partition can be found using greedy search. So I start with a partition where everything (save the first and last value) is in B. Then I gradually move the elements on the left or right side to A or C (respectively). The A partition is described by [ `idx[0]` , `idx[1]` ), B by [ `idx[1]` , `idx[2]` ) and so forth. Clear now?

Comment: @bitmask This is a really good solution for the problem you describe. I did not understand that to be the problem... potentially an edit is in order?

Comment: @bitmask can you help me to transfer it to C ? I make quite a few efforts but I just can't undesratnd the logic and what to tranfrorm from your code. I lost in main_pair functionality. What I return to main and How? I only need a number

Comment: @Opo: You might want to ask a separate question. Provide your attempt and point out where you are stuck. Feel free to link it here and do ping me again. I'll be glad to help.

Comment: @bitmask I'm very sorry I make so much noise but really I can't get your point. And what to say in the new question? Translate from C++ to C? O.o no. If you can provide a pseudocode , a very simple one, I would be happy.

Comment: @Opo: You don't have to be sorry. I'll explain: StackExchange is usually not a code-providing service (I made an exception in my answer because I thought the problem was interesting. I apologise for that). It's expected of you to try yourself first. Then when you don't know how to continue, ask a specific question, explaining why and where you are stuck. I don't know where you are stuck, so I am unable to help you with phrasing the question.

Comment: I stuck on the logic of your code. Ι only need to undesratnd the logic step by step in your code.

Comment: οκ but really I haven't understand yet the last return statement. I need only a number why to return two indexes? And how do I return it? in main I right `int Min = split_array(array);` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is your pseudocode in C (just for reference because you tagged your problem with C++ yet want a C only solution).  Still, the greedy solution that bitmask provided above is a better O(N) solution; you should try to implement that algorithm instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define N 10

int sum_array(int* array, int cnt)
{
    int res = 0;
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < cnt ; ++i)
        res += array[i];
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int array[N] = {1,1,8,1,1,3,4,9,5,2};
    int Min = 0;
    int bestA = 0, bestB = 0, bestMin = INT_MAX;
    int A, B;
    int i;
    for ( A = 0; A < N - 2; ++A)
    {
        for ( B = A + 1; B < N - 1; ++B)
        {
            int ProfitA = sum_array(array, A + 1);
            int ProfitB = sum_array(array + A + 1, B - A );
            int ProfitC = sum_array(array + B + 1, N - 1 - B );

            //here the values are "current" - valid
            Min = (ProfitA > ProfitB) ? ProfitA : ProfitB;
            Min = (ProfitC > Min) ? ProfitC : Min;

            if( Min < bestMin )
                bestA = A, bestB = B, bestMin = Min;
#if 0           
           printf( "%2d,%2d or (%3d,%3d,%3d) ", A, B, ProfitA, ProfitB, ProfitC );
           for( i = 0; i < N; ++i )
               printf( "%d%c", array[i], ( ( i == A ) || ( i == B ) ) ? '|' : ' ' );
           printf( " ==> %d\n", Min);
#endif           
        }
    }
    printf("%d @ %d, %d\n", bestMin, bestA, bestB);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok thats what I wanted! It makes the procedure of the above answers still in C! Thank you very much!

Comment: This is still O(n^3) I don't know if it matters?

Comment: @JonathanMee Well it is but it is a nice try. I working to make O(n^2), if you want to help me your free.

Answer (score 0):

I made this solution before you removed the [C++] tag so I thought I'd go ahead and post it.
It runs in *O(n*n)*:

```
const vector<int> foo{ 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 3, 4, 9, 5, 2 }; // Assumed to be of at least size 3 For pretty printing each element is assumed to be less than 10
map<vector<int>::const_iterator, pair<int, string>> bar; // A map with key: the beginning of the C partition and value: the sum and string of that partition of C
auto mapSum = accumulate(next(foo.cbegin(), 2), foo.cend(), 0); // Find the largest possible C partition sum
auto mapString = accumulate(next(foo.cbegin(), 2), foo.cend(), string(), [](const string& init, int i){return init + to_string(i) + ' ';}); // Find the largest possible C partiont string

for (auto i = next(foo.cbegin(), 2); i < foo.cend(); mapSum -= *i++, mapString.erase(0, 2)){ // Fill the map with all possible C partitions
    bar[i] = make_pair(mapSum, mapString);
}
mapSum = foo.front(); // mapSum will be reused for the current A partition sum
mapString = to_string(mapSum); // mapString will be reused for the current A partition string
cout << left;

for (auto aEnd = next(foo.cbegin()); aEnd < foo.cend(); ++aEnd){ // Iterate through all B partition beginings
    auto internalSum = *aEnd; // The B partition sum
    auto internalString = to_string(internalSum); // The B partition string

    for (auto bEnd = next(aEnd); bEnd < foo.cend(); ++bEnd){ // Iterate through all B partition endings.
        // print current partitioning
        cout << "A: " << setw(foo.size() * 2 - 5) << mapString << " B: " << setw(foo.size() * 2 - 5) << internalString << " C: " << setw(foo.size() * 2 - 4) << bar[bEnd].second << "Max Sum: " << max({ mapSum, internalSum, bar[bEnd].first }) << endl;
        internalSum += *bEnd; // Update B partition sum
        internalString += ' ' + to_string(*bEnd); // Update B partition string
    }
    mapSum += *aEnd; // Update A partition sum
    mapString += ' ' + to_string(*aEnd); // Update A partition string
}
```

Comment: Wow, can you sir make the code cleaner? I create the code I want but just for the record can you simplify your code to the minimum? Maybe with another aproach? Still in C++

Comment: @Opo I think that code is pretty well minimized... Maybe I can help explain the part[s] you don't understand? If your problem is [the one defined by bitmask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279225/range-values-in-c/28280421?noredirect=1#comment44920253_28280421) he's got a really good solution. My solution was simply designed to output all possible partitions in *O(n^2)*.

Comment: well I really don't understand. I shouldn't not use the c++11 standart only the 98. That's the first. Secondly I don't know C++ very well thats why I wanted C solutions

Comment: @Opo I've added comments on my code to try and help you. You should know that [bitmask](http://stackoverflow.com/users/430766/bitmask)'s solution uses [array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/) and [max](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/) from C++11. I use a lambda and `auto`. If you need a more customized solution than what has already been posted; if you could open a new question and link me to it, I think that would be the best way to handle it.

Comment: @Opo Sorry about the down votes; it doesn't look like you're gonna get a lot of love on that question even after I cleaned it up. I am not going to pretend to understand your constraints, but C++ is a great language. It would behoove you to learn it, starting by taking the time to figure out what [bitmask](http://stackoverflow.com/users/430766/bitmask) did! If you need help with that I'd just ask questions about the specific elements of the answer that you don't understand. Hang in there buddy: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266670/2642059